# Share data between parallel threads in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I'm newbie with Jmeter and have a question for marking web app with the scenario as below:

- Teachers are login to marking for an exam and will see the same list.
- If teacher A login and select first question, teacher B should end of the loop and go to the second question, and the same with another teacher.

Does anybody have an idea for this scenario? How to make another thread can recognize that other thread is selecting question?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea for this case for you.
You have one list of teachers in the table: **Teachers**. And you want to perform scenario teacher A login select first question then teacher B can't select the first question, teacher B just select the second question
=> You need to create a field marking status after each teacher login and question teacher select. You will check the status before the teacher select the question.

And the last question about recognizing user select question in another thread you can use: **$__V() or $__P()**;

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) useful.

It provides a [FIFO queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) which can be used for passing data between threads in a [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) (or even in different Thread Groups)

Check out [SynchronizationPluginExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx) Test Plan for reference implementation.

You can install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)